# Javascript Event Loop - Why Javascript Event Handler Work Differently

Tags: javascript, event-loop, eventhandler

please take a look at blow code

```
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerText = 'button'
document.body.appendChild(btn)

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   console.log('step1');
  },0)

  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
   console.log('step2')
  })
})
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('step3');
 },0)

  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
   console.log('step4')
 })
})
```

when I click Button element, i can see what i expected as blow

> "step2"
> "step1"
> "step4"
> "step3"

but console result is different as blow

> "step2"
> "step4"
> "step1"
> "step3"

I don't understand why this occur.
give me any answer please

Comment: There is no guarantee in what order promises are resolved/executed - unless you built it using then/await etc. Everything else is an implementation detail of the js engine. my guess is, that the "real" mouse click event happens maybe almost synchronously but the code triggered click gets deferred/scheduled-async immediately

Comment: @MarianTheisen "*that the "real" mouse click event happens maybe almost synchronously*" real mouse clicks are exactly and always asynchronous. Not "almost" whatever that would mean. "*the code triggered click gets deferred/scheduled-async immediately*" the opposite - a programmatic click is synchronous. If it was scheduled async "immediately", that means it would have been async.

Comment: @VLAZ oh yeah, you're absolutely right

Comment: "*when I click Button element, i can see what i expected as blow*" No, you do not. First of all, because it's impossible microtask queue tasks (like `.then()` handlers) are always executed with higher priority. You may *expect* "step2" -> "step1" to show before "step4" but that cannot happen. Second of all, [running your code](https://jsbin.com/xaqusip/1/edit?js,console,output) does demonstrate clearly that what you claim you get is not what you actually get. Both programatically and manually clicking results in the same order: "step2" -> "step4" -> "step1" -> "step3" micro- before macrotasks.